# The equation for how much data is produced every period

Tags: mathematical-analysis

I am trying to find out how much data we produce to project how much we will produce in the future. I find stuff like [this](https://www.forbes.com/sites/bernardmarr/2018/05/21/how-much-data-do-we-create-every-day-the-mind-blowing-stats-everyone-should-read/#306f297060ba) and [this](https://www.bbc.com/news/business-26383058):

> There are [2.5 quintillion bytes of data](https://www.domo.com/learn/data-never-sleeps-5?aid=ogsm072517_1&sf100871281=1) created each day at our current pace, but that pace is only accelerating with the growth of the Internet of Things (IoT). Over the last two years alone 90 percent of the data in the world was generated.

But that doesn't show you any research or papers outlining equations.

I am not looking for anything exact as it's not an exact thing. It's like Moore's law I imagine, sorta thing. I would simply like to know roughly an equation I could turn into some code potentially and use to type in `estimate('timestamp', 29841419481)` and get a number. Just looking for a basic math equation, I am not sure how to calculate these exponential growth type of things.

Comment: This sounds like a practical forecasting question, which could be more suitable for [stats.se], especially if there is no real domain knowledge about IoT required. In case you'd prefer to ask your question there, remember to [please not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)